# Can't clone Mercurial repo on Windows, can do it on Linux

Tags: mercurial, clone

Commands I'm using:

- server:

  hg init foo

  hg serve -R foo
- remote client:

  hg clone http://IP_ADDRESS:8000

this works on Linux, but on Windows I get:

```
destination directory: 192.168.0.122:8000
abort: The directory name is invalid: 192.168.0.122:8000
```

if I do "`hg clone http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/foo`" then I get this on server side:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 1681)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 560, in process_request_thread
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 322, in finish_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 47, in __init__
  File "SocketServer.pyc", line 617, in __init__
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 329, in handle
  File "BaseHTTPServer.pyc", line 323, in handle_one_request
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 79, in do_GET
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 70, in do_POST
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 63, in do_write
  File "mercurial\hgweb\server.pyc", line 127, in do_hgweb
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 86, in __call__
  File "mercurial\hgweb\hgweb_mod.pyc", line 118, in run_wsgi
ErrorResponse
```

I'm using Mercurial 1.7.3 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try...

```
hg clone http://IP_ADDRESS:8000 DIRNAME
```

for some directory name DIRNAME. Windows is a bit more picky about what characters can and can't be in file (or directory) names, and thus it doesn't allow things like `/` or `:`, so instead you have to give it a name for a folder to clone into.